# How do I replace a pattern using T-SQL?

Tags: sql, replace, design-patterns

I have code to normalize a POB address. For example, one of the normalizations included is:

```
set @string = replace(@string, 'pobox', 'pob')
```

Now I want to do something similar: I want to find any POB that is directly followed by a number (without a space in between) and insert a space. I want to find the pattern `like POB[0-9]` and then replace the "POB" with "POB ". How can I accomplish this? Can it be done with a simple replace? Or do I need to use some other function, like `PATINDEX`?

Comment: How many occurences do you expect per string please?

Comment: just one. Barry's solution looks great

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you are correct you can use [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)

```
Declare @searchstring varchar(50)

Set @searchstring = 'POB9090'

If (PatIndex('POB[0-9]%', @searchString) > 0)
Begin

Set @searchstring = Replace(@searchString, 'POB', 'POB ')

End

Select @searchString
```

Or probably a nicer way would be to use a `case` statement so that it can be easily incorporated in to a `select` statement

```
Declare @searchstring varchar(50)

Set @searchstring = 'POB9090'

Select Case
        When PatIndex('POB[0-9]%', @searchString) > 0 Then Replace(@searchString, 'POB', 'POB ')
        Else @searchString
        End 'SearchString'
```