# How can I make a REPLACE PATTERN in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace

I have a long NVARCHAR variable where I need to replace some pattern like this:

```
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(200) = 'Hello [PAT1] stackoverflow [PAT2] world [PAT3]'
```

I need to replace all `[PAT%]` with a blank space to look like:

```
'Hello stackoverflow world'
```

How can I do this using T-SQL in SQL Server 2008?

I was searching in other questions, and I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385649/how-do-i-replace-a-pattern-using-t-sql), but it doesn't help me, because I don't need to preserve de original part of the string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use this function for pattern replace. You can test it with this [SQL-Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92581/3/0) to test.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PatternReplace
(
   @InputString VARCHAR(4000),
   @Pattern VARCHAR(100),
   @ReplaceText VARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(4000) SET @Result = ''
   -- First character in a match
   DECLARE @First INT
   -- Next character to start search on
   DECLARE @Next INT SET @Next = 1
   -- Length of the total string -- 8001 if @InputString is NULL
   DECLARE @Len INT SET @Len = COALESCE(LEN(@InputString), 8001)
   -- End of a pattern
   DECLARE @EndPattern INT

   WHILE (@Next <= @Len) 
   BEGIN
      SET @First = PATINDEX('%' + @Pattern + '%', SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @Len))
      IF COALESCE(@First, 0) = 0 --no match - return
      BEGIN
         SET @Result = @Result + 
            CASE --return NULL, just like REPLACE, if inputs are NULL
               WHEN  @InputString IS NULL
                     OR @Pattern IS NULL
                     OR @ReplaceText IS NULL THEN NULL
               ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @Len)
            END
         BREAK
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
         -- Concatenate characters before the match to the result
         SET @Result = @Result + SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @First - 1)
         SET @Next = @Next + @First - 1

         SET @EndPattern = 1
         -- Find start of end pattern range
         WHILE PATINDEX(@Pattern, SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @EndPattern)) = 0
            SET @EndPattern = @EndPattern + 1
         -- Find end of pattern range
         WHILE PATINDEX(@Pattern, SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @EndPattern)) > 0
               AND @Len >= (@Next + @EndPattern - 1)
            SET @EndPattern = @EndPattern + 1

         --Either at the end of the pattern or @Next + @EndPattern = @Len
         SET @Result = @Result + @ReplaceText
         SET @Next = @Next + @EndPattern - 1
      END
   END
   RETURN(@Result)
END
```

[Resource link](http://dataeducation.com/splitting-a-string-of-unlimited-length/).

Comment: Thanks a lot!, for some reason I can't see, when I use brackets [] it doesn't work, but I'd changed them with parenthesis and it is working. I didn't know SQL Fiddle, is awesome!, thanks for it also.

Comment: see [this](http://www.sqllion.com/2010/12/pattern-matching-regex-in-t-sql/) explanation of the brackets! You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

+1 @Nico
, I needed a function that will remove special charters from a string, so I adjusted your function a little bit to be able to do this:

```
select dbo.PatReplaceAll('St. Martin`n tr‘an, or – in - the * field007', '[^0-9A-Z ]', '')
--Returns 'St Martinn tran or  in  the  field007'
```

Here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PatReplaceAll 
(
    @Source     varchar(8000),
    @Pattern    varchar(  50),
    @Replace    varchar( 100)
)
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    if @Source is null or @Pattern is null or @Replace is null
        return null
    if PATINDEX('%' + @Pattern + '%', @Source) = 0
        return @Source
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result varchar(8000) SET @Result = ''
    -- The remainder of the @Source to work on
    DECLARE @Remainder varchar(8000) SET @Remainder = @Source
    DECLARE @Idx INT

    WHILE (LEN(@Remainder) > 0) 
    BEGIN
        SET @Idx = PATINDEX('%' + @Pattern + '%', @Remainder)
        IF @Idx = 0 --no match - return
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = @Result +  @Remainder
                BREAK
            END
        -- Concatenate characters before the match to the result
        SET @Result = @Result + SUBSTRING(@Remainder, 1, @Idx - 1)
        -- Adjust the remainder
        SET @Remainder = SUBSTRING(@Remainder, @Idx, LEN(@Remainder) + 1 - @Idx)

        SET @Idx = 1
        -- Find the last char of the pattern (aka its length)
        WHILE PATINDEX(@Pattern, SUBSTRING(@Remainder, 1, @Idx)) = 0
            SET @Idx = @Idx + 1
        --remove the pattern from the remainder
        SET @Remainder = SUBSTRING(@Remainder, @Idx + 1, LEN(@Remainder) - @Idx)
        --Add the replace string
        SET @Result = @Result + @Replace
    END
    return @Result
END
GO
```