# find all indices of the pattern in the input string

Tags: string, t-sql

I need to find all indices of `' '` (space) and `'-'` (dash) in the input sting
Tried to use `patindex` but have several problems with that :

1. It finds only first instance of the pattern
2. How do I build a pattern ?If I set'- ' it looks for the sequence and I wand or '-' or ' '

Comment: I assume you've discounted a procedural approach using loops etc.?

Comment: yes - I prefer no loops

Comment: To answer your second question: use brackets. Example can been found in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [my answer on PatternReplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248244/how-can-i-make-a-replace-pattern-in-sql/14248625#14248625), you may simply adjust the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "dbo"."GetIndices"
(
   @InputString VARCHAR(4000),
   @Pattern VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS @indices table
(
    pos int
)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @count INT
   DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(4000) SET @Result = ''
   -- First character in a match
   DECLARE @First INT
   -- Next character to start search on
   DECLARE @Next INT SET @Next = 1
   -- Length of the total string -- 8001 if @InputString is NULL
   DECLARE @Len INT SET @Len = COALESCE(LEN(@InputString), 8001)
   -- End of a pattern
   DECLARE @EndPattern INT

   WHILE (@Next <= @Len) 
   BEGIN
      SET @First = PATINDEX('%' + @Pattern + '%', SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @Len))
      --insert into @indices( pos ) values ( @first )

      IF COALESCE(@First, 0) = 0 --no match - return
      BEGIN
         SET @Result = @Result + 
            CASE --return NULL, just like REPLACE, if inputs are NULL
               WHEN  @InputString IS NULL
                     OR @Pattern IS NULL THEN NULL
               ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @Len)
            END
         BREAK
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
         -- Concatenate characters before the match to the result
         SET @Result = @Result + SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @First - 1)
         SET @Next = @Next + @First - 1
         insert into @indices( pos ) values ( @next )
         SET @EndPattern = 1
         -- Find start of end pattern range
         WHILE PATINDEX(@Pattern, SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @EndPattern)) = 0
            SET @EndPattern = @EndPattern + 1
         -- Find end of pattern range
         WHILE PATINDEX(@Pattern, SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Next, @EndPattern)) > 0
               AND @Len >= (@Next + @EndPattern - 1)
            SET @EndPattern = @EndPattern + 1

         --Either at the end of the pattern or @Next + @EndPattern = @Len
         SET @Next = @Next + @EndPattern - 1
      END
   END
   RETURN
END
```

And use it like

```
SELECT * FROM "dbo"."GetIndices"( '1 1 1-1-1', '[- ]' )
```

See this [SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62cf3/1/0) for demo.

Result:

```
POS
2
4
6
8
```

Comment: Well.. using loops, but perhaps better than nothing!